# How to store the value of index not the array itself in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to be able to check if certain values are present in title_id, but as title_id's are index's it won't allow me to do this. Is there a way to store the values of the index without storing the array itself?

I have been searching for this answer for a long time but anything I search pulls up answers to different questions.

```
$selects = (array) null;
$res = mysqli_query($datab, "SELECT title_id FROM selects") or die($datab->error);

while ($datab = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $selects[] = $datab;
}

///////////// part of a later query
  if (!in_array($thisid, $selects)) {
            $title[] = $datab;
            $j++;
        }
```

Comment: Try `$selects[] = $datab['title_id'];`

Comment: Yes, thank you. Seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

`$selects` is array of arrays, not array of `title_id`.

Try something like that:

```
while ($datab = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $selects[] = $datab['title_id'];
}
```